# Android Native Apps Source code

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

Is there anywhere I can get the source code and all the required library files for a NATIVE android app? I need it for an experiment I am working on and I need to test a few apps for the same.

Comment: Finding open source NDK libraries and apps should not be especially difficult. For example, [a search of GitHub for `Android.mk` turns up 307,381 matches](https://github.com/search?q=android.mk&ref=cmdform&type=Code).

Comment: + there are more than dozen sample apps bundled in Android NDK

Comment: Hi! I have already done my experimenting with the NDK sample apps provided in the bundle and I am looking for higher level apps for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

First you must know all dependence in android is write in Android.mk.
Second you can find some code in android source which is connect to you purpose, then looks up its Android.mk, and can find almost you need.
At last, recommand you try ndk, and is supported by Google.